# Javascript. Php. Callback-функция отрабатывает раньше функции, которая была вызвана первой

Tags: javascript, php

Написала вот такой тестовый код:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;  



function ttt ()
{
    console.log("ttt: ", map);
    //ttt: undefined
}

function init_map(pos)
{
    map = pos;
    console.log(map);
}

function start(callback)
{
    $.get('/position.php?getVar', init_map);
    callback();
}

$(function()
{
    
   start(function() {
   ttt ();
}); 

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    Hello!

</body>
```

Функция start должна сначала брать значение из php-файла с содержимым `rnbqkbnrpppppppp11111111111111111111111111111111PPPPPPPPRNBQKBNR`, затем запускать функцию init_map, где передает значение переменной map, а уже потом выводить его в функции ttt(). Для этого я функцию ttt() вызываю коллбэком. Но все равно она вызывается раньше, чем отрабатывает init_map, судя по логам.
Что я делаю не так? Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: вы не так поняли слова которые вам написали в предыдущем вопросе.......... callback не функции start  надо делать, а функции $,get  ....... у $,get  есть callback внутри которого можно прописать любую логику, которая должна произойти после ajax запроса ...... см. мануал по $,get   https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/    ......  или на русском  https://jquery-docs.ru/jQuery.get/

Comment: причём она у вас уже прописана....и называется init_map

Comment: получается вам надо либо создать отдельную функцию в которой вывать init_map и ttt, а в callback функции $.get передавать именно  её.........либо callback сделать анонимной функцией (как в доках), в которой вызывать init_map  и ttt

Comment: @АлексейШиманский У меня в init_map передается аргумент, который цепляется из php-файла. Мне вместо init_map нужно подставить callback функцию, принимающую тот же аргумент, что и init_map, при этом содержащую  init_map и ttt?

Comment: получается что так. вам не важно что данные совпадают вам важно обработать данные и вызвыать ещё доп. функции. это можно сделать последовательно.....а это можно сделать только обобщив эти действия в одной функции (аноннимной или не анонимной)

Comment: Поняла, спасибо